# MAY BE COMING vs MAY COME

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the sentences below in meaning :

> 1. Jack may be coming to see us tomorrow.
> 2. Jack may come to see us tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *Jack may **be coming** to see us tomorrow*
> implies that even though the *speaker* doesn't know whether Jack will come or not, that matter has *already been decided*, ***to at least some extent*** (possibly because Jack himself has already decided to come, we don't know the details).

> 2: *Jack may **come** to see us tomorrow*
> is completely neutral as regards whether or not [the die is cast](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/die-is-cast) (maybe *nobody* knows if he'll come).